# useFormContext inside FormProvider is null

Tags: react-native, expo, react-hook-form

I'm using react-hook-form to handle forms and I encountered an error that only happens on iOS (works fine on android) which tell me that useFormContext is null. The code contains three components so I wrote example on expo which you can find [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@boguslaw/tenacious-carrot), as you can see I'm using FormProvider so context should be sent to the children. Anyone has any ideas how to solve it?

```
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'control')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'control')
    at FormSelect
```

```
<FormProvider {...methods}>
          <Dialog
            title={'issue-card'}
            body={
              <FormSelect
                name="card"
                label={'card-number'}
                options={cards}
              />
            }
            ...
          />
        </FormProvider>
```

```
export const FormSelect = ({
  label,
  options,
  name,
}) => {
  const { control } = useFormContext();
  const {
    field: { value, onChange },
    fieldState: { error },
  } = useController({ name, control });

  return (
    <FormControl>
        <Select
          onValueChange={onChange}
          selectedValue={value}
          variant="filled"
          _selectedItem={{ background: 'primary.black' }}
        >
          {options.map((option) => (
            <Select.Item
              key={`temporary--${value}`}
              label={option.number}
              value={option.number}
            />
          ))}
        </Select>
    </FormControl>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm adding my answer here because this is exactly the problem I just encountered and it might help someone else. For us it turns out the issue was incompatibility between versions of `react-hook-form`:

1. We had developed some components in a reusable package that used `react-hook-form@7.36.0`
2. We we were trying to use those components (via an NPM package) in a consuming project that was using `react-hook-form@7.39.0`.

Aligning the versions of `react-hook-form` made the problem go away for us.

---

In your particular case though, it looks like it's because of the way the `Dialog` control is rendering its children; if you move the `FormProvider` inside the body, then the control renders as you would expect:

```
<Dialog
  title={'issue-card'}
  body={
    <FormProvider {...methods}>
      <FormSelect
        name="card"
        label={'card-number'}
        options={cards}
      />
    </FormProvider>
  }
/>
```